# Why I have do I have intellisense on .js files but I do not have intellisense on .ts files?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
    "name": "edge-node-api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Edge Electrons customers web API",
    "main": "api.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://192.168.0.50:3000/lem/edge-node-api.git"
},
"author": "lem",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "bull": "^3.0.0-alpha.4",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "fm-log": "^4.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "memcached": "^2.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "njwt": "^0.4.0",
    "pg": "^6.2.2",
    "redis": "^2.7.1",
    "vali-date": "^1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/bull": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.22",
    "api-doc": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-develop-server": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-sequence": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.7",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
}
```

}

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2017",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Here is my typings.json:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "body-parser": "registry:npm/body-
            parser#1.15.2+20161116154925",
        "debug": "registry:npm/debug#2.0.0+20170504163145",
        "express": "registry:npm/express#4.14.0+20170217205433",
        "gulp": "registry:npm/gulp#4.0.0-alpha.2+20160817105618",
        "lodash": "registry:npm/lodash#4.0.0+20161015015725",
        "memcached": "registry:dt/memcached#2.2.0+20170324151803",
        "morgan": "registry:dt/morgan#1.7.0+20160726064905",
        "pg": "registry:npm/pg#6.0.2+20170314174547",
        "redis": "registry:npm/redis#2.6.0+20160901110043"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "globalDevDependencies": {
      "bull": "registry:dt/bull#2.1.2+20170221033156"
  }
```

}

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's hard to know without sample code. Additionally, I'd recommend fully moving away from typings to just `@types` if you're using TypeScript 2.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed

"include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],

from tsconfig.json and it worked.